# Creating dynamic tabs in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create an sample application in React and I've a doubt on creating Tabs. On clicking on a specific module, I need to open a Tab containing the items of that module. If the user clicks on the next module, then another tab should be created dynamically without closing the first tab. In the same way I want to open new tabs dynamically without closing the already opened ones. Is this possible in React?

Comment: It is possible. Most basically you can have a component to manage tabs (1), and a component for the content of the active tab (2). Active tab information can be passed as props from 1 to 2 and you can use componentDidUpdate lifecycle method in 2 to change the content when the active tab changed.

Comment: @AliAnkarali: But if we do that way, if we open the 1st tab from 2nd, then the content of the 1st tab needs to be passed. Correct? I need the 1st tab to stay as such without passing the content as the content should have been already loaded.